# USB flash drive won't show up as a bootable option on a laptop with Endless OS installed on it

Tags: boot, usb, asus-laptop

I recently bought a new laptop (Asus VivoBook Max) and it came in with Endless OS and so I wanted to install Windows 10 instead. I formated a USB flash drive as NTFS format and put Windows 10 on it using Rufus.

When I plug the USB flash drive into the laptop it will recognize that there is a USB flash drive, but won't show it as a bootable option. What can I do to change this so I can boot from the USB flash drive?

P.S Secure Boot and Fast Boot are disabled.

[image]

Comment: Any of the answers below works? Mind sharing the solution (to other Asus fan..) ?

Answer (score 1):

It’s in your laptop BIOS. Look for instructions on how to enter your BIOS and what needs to be done to have the laptop ready for Windows 10 as well as other boot options that you would find in the boot options in your bios menu.

For example my laptop came with Windows 10 but since I replaced the hard drive and don’t have Windows 10 disc I installed Windows 7. I had to go to my BIOS and change the boot compatibility to work with Windows 7 and below.

I think it said something about EFI or something like that is what Windows 8 and above use.

Answer (score 1):

You are in UEFI BIOS already. See the screenshot again, this time look at the bottom.

Press <kbd>F8</kbd> for the boot menu. This is where you should be shown the list of all devices/options available and you need to rearrange the order. Save it and reboot.

Should work now.

What you see in that screenshot under "USB Port" is the list of available ports and attached devices. BIOS just detects and shows the device. I have not see any BIOS mentioning whether a device is bootable or not. If the device is not bootable, it'll show up during the booting process, not in BIOS.

Comment: I just realized after answering that this question was posted last year. I guess it's too late, but anyway would be nice to hear if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to enable this in the bios settings by holding the <kbd>F2</kbd> key ([according to this](https://www.asus.com/uk/support/FAQ/1008829/)) during power on then picking "Enter Setup" from the menu.

This will normally take you to a blue backed screen where you can pick your start up options. ([see here](http://www.boot-disk.com/boot_priority.htm))

***WARNING*** Don't change anything unless you understand it - it's easy to break ALOT of things in these screens